# Programmatically add Magento products to categories

Tags: magento, categories

I am using Magento 1.4.0.1.
I have over 21000 simple products, each entered into a single category.
There are hundreds of categories in my site.
Some products belong in multiple categories.
Is there some way for me to programmatically add products into multiple categories?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In PHP code you can put them into the category while you are importing them.

Say you have a product called $product and a category ID called $category_id

You can set the categories which a product belongs to by doing the following

```
$categories = array($category_id);
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
```

If the product already has categories and you'd like to add one more then you can use `getCategoryIds()` like this:

```
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
$categories[] = $categoryId;
$product->setCategoryIds($categories);
$product->save();
```

Or, as mentioned by Joshua Peck in the comments, you can use the `category_api` model to add or remove a product from a category without affecting it's current category assignments:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
  ->assignProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
  ->removeProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

Comment: Hi Josh,
Thanks for this, but the products are already in Magento, I just need them to be added to multiple categories (or assigning multiple categories to each product in most cases).

Comment: Then all you have to do is load up the product and do the setCategoryIds() function and save it. If you want to do more than one category you can put more than one category_id into that array.

Comment: From this it's not clear, this overwrite categories or adds to them?

Comment: This would overwrite the assigned categories for that product. To add to the categories you would assign $product->getCategoryIds() to a variable, add your IDs to the array, then setCategoryIds(), then save.

Comment: I just want to add that you can remove and add with getSingleton category API: `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId());` and `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($category->getId(),$product->getId());` This will not overwrite any categories the product is already in.

Comment: @JoshuaPack Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @user3409662 I went ahead and added it as an answer.

Comment: Saving a product like this is too dangerous and you could do some damage if you're not careful. I suggest @JoshuaPack answer below.

Comment: @JoshPennington Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298467/57334 thanks

Answer (score 19):

I just want to add that you can remove and add with getSingleton category API:

To Remove product from category:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->removeProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

To Add Product to Category:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')->assignProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());
```

This will not overwrite any categories the product is already in

Comment: this is the best answer here

Comment: Why it is breaking loop foreach($products as $prod)? I can't manage to run it through whole product collection.

Comment: @versedi I do not see it breaking loop. I have it run through 100,000 product SKUs. I would do a try catch and see if an error is happening and why.

Comment: Be aware that Magento will run category/product reindex after `assignProduct`/`removeProduct` call, so this is not quite a sustainable solution for assigning huge batches of products/categories.

Comment: this is slow as hell but faster than save the product ... my answer gives more speed to your needs

Answer (score 2):

You can write a module (which takes time but potentially quicker at importing your data) or you can put something together with the API (less involving of Magento programming but potentially slower at importing your data).

Your starting point of what-you-know-already, how valuable your time is and how often you will need to run the update should determine your choice.

Here is the Magento API documentation for adding products to categories (see example at foot of page):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_category

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Can you clarify for me the UpdateCategory method - will that method allow me to assign a product into additional (multiple) categories? Or will it overwrite the existing category assigned?

Comment: I was hoping you would get some answer by a programming wizard on this - I would untick if I were you to egg them on... This depends on how you see the task - categories first or products. If you loop through the products then you definitely can assign them to multiple categories - that will be 'assigning categories to products' not 'assigning products to categories'. Start with product update API code for that, not catalogue update. There are better ways, but at least with API you can get your algorithms working.

Comment: Thanks for the update - assigning categories to products sounds much better... perhaps someone has already written such a piece of code and would be happy to share it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well I ended up doing this with the API for some reason of laziness. This adds all the visible products into the category with ID 146:

```
<?php
  $client= new SoapClient('http://www.example.com/api/soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => 1, "connection_timeout" => 120));

  // Can be added in Magento-Admin -> Web Services with role set to admin

  $sess_id= $client->login('apiuser', 'apikey');

  // Get the product list through SOAP
  $filters = array('visibility' => '4', 'status' => '1');
  $all_products=$client->call($sess_id, 'product.list', array($filters));

  // Now chuck them into category 146

  foreach($all_products as $product)
  {  //var_dump($product);
      echo $product['sku']."\n";
      $doit=$client->call($sess_id, 'category.assignProduct', array('146', $product['sku']));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Mathew, can you explain a little more about the code you posted here please? e.g. what does $filters = array('visibility' => '4', 'status' => '1'); refer to?

Comment: visibility 4 is catalog/search, status 1 is enabled. Hence it is not putting gazillions of simples in the 'everything' catalog (which for me was ID 146).

Comment: Is possible can i use API in localhost.

Answer (score 1):

After looking into the Magento API: Magento adds products to categories in the following way:

```
public function assignProduct($categoryId, $productId, $position = null, $identifierType = null)
{
    $category = $this->_initCategory($categoryId);
    $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
    $productId = $this->_getProductId($productId);
    $positions[$productId] = $position;
    $category->setPostedProducts($positions);

    try {
        $category->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}
```

And getting all the asigned products:

```
public function assignedProducts($categoryId, $store = null)
{
    $category = $this->_initCategory($categoryId);

    $storeId = $this->_getStoreId($store);
    $collection = $category->setStoreId($storeId)->getProductCollection();
    ($storeId == 0)? $collection->addOrder('position', 'asc') : $collection->setOrder('position', 'asc');;

    $result = array();

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'position'   => $product->getPosition()
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best above answer points to use `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
  ->assignProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());`

Anyway that function is pretty slow in case you have a lot of products/categories to update.

This is because the api function `assignProduct()`:

- only accept 1 product/category at time
- for every call it loads the product and the category and then save the category
  ( very slow in case you need to update the same category multiple times )

For example suppose you want to assign 10 products to 1 category ... it gonna load and save the same category 10 times ...
 ( and load all product that is not actually required if you are sure you product ids are corrects)

**A faster way**
I came up with the below function that is the same as the api one but it loads and save the category only **one time**.

This function accept an array as parameter `$data` that needs to contains all collect changes in the form of `$category_id => array(all the products you want to assign)`

It is trivial to customize it as for your needs adding, for example, a parameter for `store_id` ( the function use 0 by default)  and position information to the products ...

**Add category**

```
function assignCategories($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $cat_id => $products_ids) {
        /** @var  $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->load($cat_id );

        $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
        foreach ($products_ids as $pid) {
            $positions[$pid] = null;
        }
        $category->setPostedProducts($positions);
        $category->save();
    }
}
```

**Remove category**

```
function removeProduct($data)
{
    foreach ($data as $cat_id => $products_ids) {
        /** @var  $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->setStoreId(0)
            ->load($cat_id);

        $positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
        foreach ($products_ids as $pid) {
            unset($positions[$pid]);
        }
        $category->setPostedProducts($positions);
        $category->save();
    }
}
```

**note**

Saving the category trigger the `Category Flat Data` and `Catalog URL Rewrites` reindex ( if they are set as `update on save` ).
This is not exactly fast ( the API call does the same ) ...
... so you may want to set these reindex to update manually before running your changes and then do a full reindex on them after
( depending on the number of categories/product you are updating this could be the best option )

Answer (score 0):

We can assign multiple products to the category programmatically using magento scripts. Please create an array of the categories and the select the products based on the custom attribute or field.

```
$newproducts = $product->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'attribute_label', 'eq'=> 'attribute_id')));
```

Loop through the products and assign to category as shown below.

```
$newCategory = array( $list[0] , $list[$key]); 
foreach ($newproducts as $prod)
{
    $prod->setCategoryIds(array_merge($prod->getCategoryIds(), $newCategory));
    $prod->save();
}
```

Please refer [my tutorial](http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-create-new-categories-and-assigned-products-to-category-programmatically-magento/) which gives a step by step explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to assign the categories to the products.
Reference from core code - app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category.php

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$categoryProductTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category_product');
$productData = array();$position=0;
foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    $productData[] = array(
        'category_id' => (int)$catId1,
        'product_id'  => (int)$product->getId(),
        'position'    => (int)$position
    );
$productData[] = array(
        'category_id' => (int)$catId2,
        'product_id'  => (int)$product->getId(),
        'position'    => (int)$position
    );
}

$write->insertMultiple($categoryProductTable, $productData);
```