# Which file should I use when assigning products to a category in Magento programatically?

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

I am new to Magento. I have created a category in the back end of Magento. There are quite few threads about how to assign a product to a category, however I don't understand which file should I use to use that code:

- [Programatically add Magento products to categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491548/programatically-add-magento-products-to-categories)
- [How to assign categories for products in magento Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548352/how-to-assign-categories-for-products-in-magento-programmatically)
- [Magento wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/catalog_category)

If I understand correctly, the page is generated automatically by Magento, when you create a category and assign products to it. I know there is a `view.phtml` file which is a template of how the webpage should look like. Thank you in advance, guys. Will be waiting for your respond.

Comment: better to ask on: http://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost eight years have passed since I've asked this question. I see now how bad the question is. I should have explained what I want in the first place; and now I can't even recall.

This is how I would approach the problem:

1. Create a service class that assigns products to the category. Perhaps create an interface that takes the product entity or the product ID as the first argument, and a category ID as the second.
2. Reference that service class in another place depending on when I want that population to happen. There are many places:

   1. Controller (either FE or BE) action (perhaps a button)
   2. Data Patch or Install Script (to make sure the changes exist in any environment)
   3. Console command (if desired to execute via bin/magento command)
   4. Cron script, if needs to be a recurring operation
   5. Observer or a plugin if needs to happen when some specific event occurs.
   6. API request, if needed to be triggered from the outside of Magento.

I wasn't aware of these things back in the day. And I wish I would have received this answer back then. I hope it helps other developers who start with the framework and don't know how to structure the app.

Answer (score 0):

Code examples like that is for developers (which I'm kind of guessing you're primarily not) to put into their own modules, maybe as an observer running on the product save event.

For you I would instead recommend testing out snippets like that in small freestanding files in your magento-folder.  At least until you know how to make a proper module this is the easiest way to run some custom code, that perhaps only needs to run once.

Create file `triggerCustomAction.php` in your Magento root directory, making it accessible from www.yourdomain.com/triggerCustomAction.php to run it once.

Use this as a starting point, with code you need to run at the bottom of the file:

```
<?php

require 'app/Mage.php';
if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// this can be changed from to any store ID number like this:
// Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(xx);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

//enter your code to run below here:
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a developer. However was confused which file should I use.

Comment: Well it all depends on when you want the code to run. My example above is for a manual trigger when you enter the URL to the script, but gives you access to all Magento specific objects and functionality.  If you need to auto-add _all_ new products to a specific category you should probably Google for guides on how to make a module, specifically one that listens to the `catalog_product_save_after` event in an observer. I think you could do it with a small module of just 3-4 files, with main code in `myModule/Model/Observer.php`.