# Magento - How to add multiple products to categories fast

Tags: magento, product, categories

I'm having a major problem, which is really time consuming, so I was hoping someone has a good solution for me to save both time and effort...

I am managing a Magento shop for a client of mine and after a redesign we now developed a new navigation structure.
Problem is that now I have to edit every single product and assign it to the new categories, so we can launch the new navigation.
Fortunately I only have to edit the active products, but it's still about 1,300 in total.

Is there any way to go about it smarter?
The shop is selling furniture and accessoires, so I could do searches for products like sofas for example and add all of them to the categories.

I know that I have the option of going to the categories and go to the "assigned products" tab and assign products there, but that doesn't really work for me since the search options are very limited (can't search for active products, can't distinguish between simple and configurable products etc...)

Hoping for some input here, because I don't want to spend about 30 hours on this!

Thanks for every suggestion y'all can come up with :)

Comment: I wish that could share some code that you may have but have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512286/1380867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah there is one solution .. First you have to export all product data in excel sheet from your site than edit it as per your requirement and import it again .. I hope it will work..

Comment: I like what you are saying but I am not sure that was the expected answer

Comment: Broadly I think this is the right way. You could use Magmi as it has some nice filters that might help.

Comment: Worked like a charm, used magmi to import the products after editing. Saved me like 30 hours of work!

Answer (score 0):

you can add product in category with following code

```
 $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();
$new_order = 0;
foreach($categories as $category){
    $cat_api = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Api;
    $productsids = array('1');
    foreach ($productsids as $id){
       $cat_api->assignProduct($category->getId(), $id, $new_order);
    }
}
```

$productids is array you can give multiple product id in array.

Comment: Thank you, but it's a little bit more complicated than that, since I pretty much have to put every product into different categories. Some products can be used indoors and outdoors and so on... So I'm liking the idea of exporting everything, working on it in Excel with some rules and then reimporting it using magmi.